# systemd service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, systemd

I am trying to run an SSH command in a systemd service. Although I the user I set to run the command `fedora` has permission to everything the command requires (verified by both running the command manually in a logged-in shell without failure and permission checks on the files), it still gives the error of permission denied.

```
[Unit]
Description=AutoSSH tunnel
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -f -TN -L 3333:localhost:3333 -o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes" -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -i /home/fedora/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@server
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pkill -f 3333:localhost:3333
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
User=fedora
Group=fedora

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

error message:

```
Oct 16 11:10:47 Lenovoserver systemd[2318595]: autossh-tunnel.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Oct 16 11:10:47 Lenovoserver systemd[2318595]: autossh-tunnel.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/ssh: Permission denied
```

Permission checks:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 808832 Oct  9  2019 /usr/bin/ssh
```

`fedora` user has permission to execute `/usr/bin/ssh`

```
-rw-------. 1 fedora fedora 2610 Jan  3  2020 /home/fedora/.ssh/id_rsa
```

`fedora` user has read access to its private key.

Did I do anything wrong or is this a `systemd` bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be **SELinux**, the new ssh port has to be registered in selinux. 
Firs check if the service work by disabling selinux temporarily, if it works add ssh port to selinux as follow.

```
# Check selinux status
sestatus

# Disable selinux temporarily
setenforce 0

# Check selinux ssh port 
semanage port -l | grep ssh
ssh_port_t                     tcp      22

# Add selinux ssh port 
sudo semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 3333

# Check selinux ssh port 
semanage port -l | grep ssh
ssh_port_t                     tcp      22, 3333
```

Comment: Thank you. it's one of the causes. the other being `ssh -f` flag, it means running the command in background, thus the service exits immediately after running.